# Inserting Maple worksheet commands

Tags: maple

In Maple, it's very easy to delete a line or command in a worksheet (cmd-backspace), but how would I insert a line in the middle of a worksheet?

Comment: clicking the [> icon with cursor at the end of the line above where you want to insert works for me

Comment: Please ask this at the Maple forums if you didn't find anything in their knowledge base. This site is about mathematics and not about a tool for computation.

Comment: For Maple related questions, you may want to consider MaplePrimes.

Comment: Figured it out... Insert>Execution Group>After cursor (cmd-J)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your cursor, click the place you would like to enter your new line. Then, near the top of Maple, there should be a toolbar with a button that looks like  "[>". If you press this button, it will start a new line. I posted a picture below; the button circled in red is the one you should press.

[image]